# How to calculate value for subtotal with operations in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

Here the scenario, there are have radio button which it will checked radios that have 1 as "value", and the total will displayed in sub_total. I already get the value of sub_total but in this situation the sub_total must be in % value and have an operations.This is operations of sub_total:

"value"/4*30% = _____%

Here is my js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $radios = $(':radio[name^="que_"]').change(function () {

        var totalPrice = $radios.filter(function () {
            return this.checked && this.value === '1'
        }).length;
        $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);
    });
    $radios.first().change()
});
```

Here is my html code as references:

```
    <td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_3',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_3',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_4',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_4',1,null) !!}</td>
```

Anyone can help me to show how it's work ?

Comment: var percentage = parseFloat(4 / 100)
var total = value * percentage;

Comment: Thank You for helping me, i also try this one and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
parseInt(totalPrice / 4 * 0.3 * 100) + '%'
```

Comment: Thank You for helping me, i had been tried it and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calculating the total price you will want to use the built in `Math.round()` rounding function.

**Math.round():**

> The **`Math.round()`** function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

We can make it work for decimals like seen below. Though if you wish to have zero decimal places it might be better to use `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()` instead, so you can round the number up or down whenever it suits you best.

**Here is an example:** (run the snippet)

```js
var totalPrice = 11;

// two decimal places
var result2Dec = Math.round(totalPrice * 0.3 * 100 / 4)/100 + '%';
// one decimal place
var result1Dec = Math.round(totalPrice * 0.3 * 10 / 4)/10 + '%';
// no decimal places
var result0Dec = Math.round(totalPrice * 0.3 / 4) + '%';

console.log('This is two decimals ' + result2Dec);
console.log('This is one decimal ' + result1Dec);
console.log('This is zero decimals ' + result0Dec);
```